# jsp requests image from servlet works only on localhost

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet called LineImage that creates a jpeg based on the parameters supplied to it. I use a servlet because the parameters vary for every user. The parameters are passed from another servlet with a string. I embed the image in a jsp with (for example)

```
<img src=LineImage?param1=0&param2=6&param3=3&param4=-6&param5=0&param6=0&param7=6 />
```

Servlet is mapped with

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LineImage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Lines.LineImage</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LineImage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LineImage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I run my code on localhost everything works perfect. When I upload the .war to aws and use the website the image doesn't load correctly. What would change from localhost to the website that would break this?

Comment: You aren't giving any much to work with. To start, what is the client retrieving instead?

Comment: Sorry I'm nor completely sure I understand the question. If I view Javascript Console for the malformed page it shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://www.mywebsitename.com/LineImage?param1=-4&param2=-9&param3=-2&param4=-1&param5=0&param6=0&param7=3`

Comment: Well, your servlet apparently threw an exception. Just open `http://www.mywebsitename.com/LineImage?param1=-4&param2=-9&param3=-2&param4=-1&p‌​aram5=0&param6=0&param7=3` directly in browser address bar to see the error page in its full glory. Or just read the server logs for the exception and stacktrace. The information provided by the exception is at its own the whole answer to your concrete problem.

Comment: `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder, but interface was expected
 Lines.LineImage.doGet(LineImage.java:189)` Does this arise because my localhost and aws are using a different JVM? Here is the referenced line `JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out).encode(image);`

Comment: That's really strange. This would suggest that you've included a copy of the JRE/JDK (or a part of it containing the `JPEGImageEncoder` class) as JAR file in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. Is this true?

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way, I struggle with some of this. My build/web/WEB-INF/lib conatins 5 jars: `common-codec-1.6-javadoc.jar, common-codec-1.6-sources.jar, common-codec-1.6-tests.jar, common-codec-1.6.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar`. I believe I downloaded the common-codec files when learning the jpeg part. Did I do this wrong? Should these not be there?